# I am trying to perform a Caesar shift on the character z (ASCII 122). How do I give it "more room" to prevent it from overflowing past 127?

Tags: c, arrays, cryptography, cs50, caesar-cipher

In the CS50 2019 Caesar assignment, I am supposed to perform Caesar shifts on characters by a given number of letters (`key`).

To do this, I add the value of `key` to each letter, as such:

```
for each character in plaintext:
    plaintext[character] += key
```

Since I want `z` to loop back to `a`, I then wrote:

```
while (ciphered_character > 122)
{
    ciphered_character -= 26;
}
```

Running the program with `plaintext` of `z` and a `key` of `26` causes `26` to be added to `z` (which is represented by `122`). This causes `plaintext[character]` to overflow (past 127, I presume) and become negative before the `while` loop even kicks in. This gives a garbage output.

I know I can check for potential overflows beforehand and subtract `26` first, but that complicates my code. Can I give the variable 'more room' to prevent it from overflowing?

Do I use a different data type? What is the best practice here?

Comment: What result do you expect for `z + 26`?  I could see multiple correct answers to that!

Comment: One natural approach is to first shift your characters to 0 to 25 (by subtracting `'a'`) then do the actual Caesar shift using modular arithmetic, then shift back to ascii by adding `'a'`)

Comment: @yeojunjie It is the same problem as with binary shift operator for integer types. Your program should just set an error if the passed key is equal to the number of characters in the alphabet.

Comment: Don't use characters.  `'a'` is an int.  `'z'` is an int.  `'z' + 26` does not overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only care about lower case then this will work for you:

```
for each character in plaintext:
   plaintext[character] = (plaintext[character] - 'a' + key) % 26 + 'a'
```

Subtracting 'a' to give you a value of 0-25, then add the key.  If there is a overflow the modulo will give you the updated value in the 0-25 range which is added back to 'a' to get the correct character.

If you do need to handle both upper and lower case then you will need two different cases - one using 'a' and the other using 'A'.  Select the the correct case for each character by checking isupper(plaintext[character])

Comment: Thank you -- your answer works best for my case. This also reminds me that I can directly do math and comparisons with `'a'` instead of having to look up its integer equivalent, `97`.

Answer (score 1):

Fun project;

I did it like [this](https://ideone.com/pLHA1D), assuming ASCII and using the full range of printable characters, from `Space` to `~`

```
void caeser_shift(char* text, int key)
{ while (*text) { *text++ = ((*text-' ') + key) %('~'-' ') + ' '; } }

int main(void)
{
    char plaintext[] = "Hello World; This is a test.";

    caeser_shift(plaintext, 26);

    printf("%s\n", plaintext);

    return 0;
}
```

## Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4520KB
b!((+:q+.( U:n$%/:%/:{:0!/0H
```